# Access to different xml elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I would like to know if there is a way to access elements from different layouts in a `Fragment` class, something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.activity_layout_1, container, false);
View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.activity_layout_2, container, false);

TextView textView1= (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView textView2= (TextView) view2.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

textView2.setText("text changed");
}
```

This is what I want to achieve [image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What does the XML look like for the activity which holds this fragment?

Comment: I will try to explain it the bes I can, I have a containter xml that contains a SearchView  and a SlidingTab this SlidingTab contains 3 tabs with 1 Fragment per tab, what im trying to do is to acces to the SearchView from one of the fragments so I can make a filter function but when I run my code it never enters to the searchView's listener.

Comment: Is the "search view" a button in the ActionBar? What do you want to accomplish by accessing it?

Comment: Yes the [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) its in the ActionBar and by accessing it I want to set its listener and implement a filter logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add menu items to the `ActionBar`, you should override `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. You can do this in either an Activity or a Fragment. The "listener" is actually the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method, also within the Activity or Fragment subclass which created the menu. For details, check out the [Menus API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

If you are targetting API 23 (Marshmallow), you should look at `Toolbar`. Even for older versions, you can use `Toolbar` from the appcompat library.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work as written. What it will look like will depend upon the `container`. And, depending upon how you are setting up the fragment, you might not have control over `container`

Another options is to [use `<include>` instead](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html), for greater control. You have one layout that uses `<include>` elements to reference the ones that you want to reuse and, if needed, provide right containers for it all to work.